# Sync browsing history and bookmarks with Firefox and Brave

Tags: firefox, sync, bookmarks, history, brave

I just recently switched from Firefox to Brave. I managed to import all my bookmarks to Brave but still couldn't find a way to import all the histories. Also, brave sync is still in beta. So, I am looking for a way to sync browsing history & bookmarks within Firefox and Brave.

I read all the questions related to my query in superuser. But all the answers only talked about syncing bookmarks. All of them miss the "browsing history" matter.

Comment: According to the documentation, Brave import does bookmarks & history.

Comment: Look, even the 'firefox' option is also not available: https://imgur.com/a/spSrjNo